# Problem with Windows search service

Tags: windows-7, search, services

I have a problem with windows search service. Although it is enabled in "Control panel/Programs/Turn Windows features on or off", it is disabled in services.msc. Because of that search in windows explorer and start menu don't work. Is there any way to run this service?

[image]

P.S. I've just installed some third-party software, this may be the reason.

Comment: What does Admin Tools, Event Viewer say? Mine says... "The Windows Search Service has failed to create the new search index. Internal error <1, 0x80070003, Failed to create application directory: I:\WindowSearchIndex\Search\Data\Applications\>. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for the third party software, it is possible that it has disabled the service - you may want to uninstall it or find out the reasons in case they conflict with each other.

However, to enable a disabled service, all you do is:

Go in to computer management, (Click the `Start Orb` > Right click on `Computer` > Click on `Manage`)

Next, go down to `Services and Applications` > `Services` and look for `Windows Search Service`

Make sure that this is set to `Automatic (Delayed Start)`.

[image]

Edit based on comments.

I have no idea why the service would not be there if it is installed correctly. At your own risk, you can recreate the service by typing the following at a command prompt:

```
SC create WSearch binPath= "C:\Windows\system32\SearchIndexer.exe /Embedding"
```

Comment: I've looked through the list of service 3 times but didn't find "Windows Search". Is there any solution?

Comment: @Sergey - I have no idea why it wouldn't be there other than third party software - updating answer now

Comment: Now there is a WSearch service. When I tried to start it, I've got "Windows could not start the WSearch service on Local Computer. Error 2: the system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: @Sergey - to undo it, type "SC delete wsearch" clearly something is wrong, the Windows Search application is not installed on your machine. Try unticking in windows components then reinstalling.

Comment: The reason for Wsearch and not the friendly name is because I didn't specify in the command above.

Comment: >>then reinstalling
How can I get Windows Search reinstalled? I found this application only for XP and Vista. Or did you mean reinstalling Windows?

Comment: @Sergey I mean, go to windows components and untick Windows Search, click ok - then go back and tick it and click ok.

Comment: @Wil I went to Control Panel - Programs - Programs and Features - Turn Windows features on and off, unticked Windows Search (somehow it was there) and got "An error has occured. Not all of the features were successfully changed."

Comment: @Sergey - that is because for some reason it isn't installed! see if you can now add it.

Comment: Tried to google how to add it - couldn't find anything. I uploaded the screenshot of the troubleshooter, maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Although I gave up you helped me understand the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Tried a few other things and finally I gave up and reinstalled Windows. Now I have a habit to create restore points!